# How to get user friendly values of Sine function?

Tags: java, android, calculator, trigonometry

I am working on an android Calculator application which can calculate trigonometric functions.

My question is "How do i get my Calculator to show correct values of Sine function?" i.e.; `Sin 90° = 1`, but it shows the value of `Sin 90° = 0.893996663600`. I am using Eclipse to make this app.

This is my Code for Sine function:

```
ImageButton btnSin;
TextView txtDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSin);
    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

    btnSin.setOnClickListener(this);

}

Double total = 0.0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSin) {
    if (txtDisplay.getText().equals("")) {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
    }
    else {
        total = Math.sin(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()));
        txtDisplay.setText("");
        txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
    }
}
```

Comment: sin() takes radians as a parameter, not degrees.

Comment: So, how do I convert radians to degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math.sin() expects an argument in radians so you can use

```
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString())));
```

If you had the need to convert the opposite way you could have used

```
Math.toDegrees(double radians)
```

Formulas are:

```
radians = degrees * (π/180)
degrees = radians * (180/π)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

Modifying the Code by changing

```
if (txtDisplay.getText().equals("")) {
    txtDisplay.setText("");
}
else {
    total = Math.sin(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()));
    txtDisplay.setText("");
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
}
```

to

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
if (value % 90 == 0) {
    double total = 0.0;
    total = Math.round(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()))));
    txtDisplay.setText("");
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
}
else if (value % 60 != 0 && value % 30 == 0) {
    total = Math.floor(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString())))) + 0.5;
    txtDisplay.setText("");
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
}
else {
    total = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString())));
    txtDisplay.setText("");
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
}
```

solved my problem.

So, my new Code is:

```
ImageButton btnSin;
TextView txtDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSin);
    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

    btnSin.setOnClickListener(this);

}

Double total = 0.0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSin) {
        double value = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        if (value % 90 == 0) {
            double total = 0.0;
            total = Math.round(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()))));
            txtDisplay.setText("");
            txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
        }
        else if (value % 60 != 0 && value % 30 == 0) {
            total = Math.floor(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString())))) + 0.5;
            txtDisplay.setText("");
            txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
        }
        else {
            total = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString())));
            txtDisplay.setText("");
            txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
        }
    }
```